# Timer Script Supplied by Google not happy

Tags: javascript, timer

Having a little hiccup with a code supplied to us from Google for a timer on some dynamic ad creatives.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    // Calculate time left till 1600 ZA (1400 GMT)
    var currTime = new Date();
    var endTime = new Date(currTime.getFullYear(),currTime.getMonth(),currTime.getDay(), 14, 0, 0, 1);
    var timeLeft = (endTime - currTime) / 1000;
    var display = document.querySelector('#time');
    if (timeLeft > 0) {
    startTimer(timeLeft, display);
  }
};

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>Registration closes in <span id="time">00:00</span> minutes!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Viewing the HTML of the code just displays the following line:

**Registration closes in 00:00 minutes!**

As it stands now it isn't doing anything and I believe in the collective knowledge of the Internet in helping working it out :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: My apologies, going to edit the post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this date calculation (see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours):

```js
    var currTime = new Date();
    var endTime = new Date();
    endTime.setHours(14,0,0,0);
    var timeLeft = (endTime.getTime() - currTime.getTime()) / 1000;
    alert(timeLeft);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're constructing the `endTime` by using `getDay()` - this returns the day of the week, with 0 being Sunday.  You need to use `getDate()`, which will return the day of the month:

```
var endTime = new Date(currTime.getFullYear(),currTime.getMonth(),currTime.getDate(), 14, 0, 0, 1);
```

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    // Calculate time left till 1600 ZA (1400 GMT)
    var currTime = new Date();
    var endTime = new Date(currTime.getFullYear(),currTime.getMonth(),currTime.getDate(), 14, 0, 0, 0);
    
    var timeLeft = (endTime - currTime) / 1000;
    var display = document.querySelector('#time');
    
    if (timeLeft > 0) {
    startTimer(timeLeft, display);
  }
};
```

```html
<div>Registration closes in <span id="time">00:00</span> minutes!</div>
```

Note that these calculations depend entirely on the date/time set on the client computer - if you have something important dependent on this, you should retrieve the time from a server you trust.

Comment: Thanks for the help.